# Excel: How do I make excel read my date values properly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column of dates in a custom format `d\m\yyyy h:mm` for example

`11/10/2016 17:33`

The problem is that the values are actually in `m\d\yyyy h:mm`

So in this case `10` is actually the day. How do I make excel understand this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit easier:

1. Select the cell you want to format
2. Push Ctrl+1 or Cmd+1
3. Under the "Number" tab, click on "Custom" at the bottom of the "Category" list
4. In the "Type" box, type in your format. In your case `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`
5. Click "OK" and that should do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to do it.

First I convert the format from custom to text by inserting a `'` before the cells.

Then I split the column into date and time to get them separately

after that i use the following formula
`=DATE(2017,LEFT(A4,FIND("/",A4)-1),MID(A4,FIND("/",A4)+1,FIND("/",A4,FIND("/",A4)+1)-FIND("/",A4)-1))`

and then i join them again.

Thanks for nothing folks haha..im just kidding

If someone has a more efficient way to this please post